# Using union with Group by in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use union between to select statements and group by the department name field , in logic it should run smoothly but the outcome is strange it shows duplicate rows .

```
SELECT departments.name,
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'MISSED' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming_missed,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Station Busy' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming_busy,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Normal' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming_answered,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'MISSED' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network_missed,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Station Busy' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network_busy,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Normal' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network_answered
FROM
    call_classification_dim, call_flags, departments, fct_calls, flags
WHERE
    (fct_calls.id = call_flags.call_id)
        AND (call_flags.flag = flags.id)
        AND (fct_calls.call_direction_id = call_classification_dim.id)
        AND (fct_calls.on_network_called_department_id = departments.id)
        AND (departments.id > 2)
        AND (fct_calls.call_direction_id = 3)
        GROUP BY departments.name
  UNION 
  SELECT departments.name,
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'MISSED' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming_missed,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Station Busy' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming_busy,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'Incoming' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Normal' THEN 1
        END) AS total_incoming_answered,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'MISSED' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network_missed,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Station Busy' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network_busy,
        COUNT(CASE
            WHEN direction_name = 'On Network' THEN 1
        END
            AND CASE
            WHEN description = 'Normal' THEN 1
        END) AS total_on_network_answered
FROM
    call_classification_dim, call_flags, departments, fct_calls, flags
WHERE
    (fct_calls.id = call_flags.call_id)
        AND (call_flags.flag = flags.id)
        AND (fct_calls.call_direction_id = call_classification_dim.id)
        AND (fct_calls.on_network_calling_department_id = departments.id)
        AND (departments.id > 2)
        AND (fct_calls.call_direction_id = 2)
GROUP BY departments.name
```

the result should be 3 rows combining the data from the two select statements and grouped by the department name, instead it show 6 rows as the two select statements are called separately without join .